# find with escaped glob expansion works on command line; not in Java Runtime.exec

Tags: java, bash, find, exec, glob

I'm running this command:

```
find /tmp/thumbnailgenerator/processor -maxdepth 1 -amin +1 -type f -iname 'a*' -delete
```

which works as expected when run from the command line. But when run as a singular command in Java via `Runtime.getRuntime.exec(String command)`, the files are not deleted. (Yes they are one minute old.) Also when run as a command array `cmdarray` that joins to the above string via `StringUtils.join(cmdarray, ' ')`, it still does not work.

I suspect this has to do with the glob expansion since I know a common mistake in using `Runtime.exec` is to assume it does glob expansion like bash does, but deleting `*` does not help (it still won't delete file `a`).

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with how the first round of processing is performed by bash v. exec, but not exactly glob expansion. Remove the `' '` around the filename and it should work. In bash, you use those quotes to *prevent* bash from expanding the glob. However single quote has no special meaning to exec either, so those are passed raw to the find command too. You want find to see `a*`. In bash, this means you must type `'a*'`. But in exec, it means you must type `a*` or else find will see `'a*'`.

Comment: ... and it *should* work? You posted the question and the answer and didn't test it?

Comment: @AlexandreSantos it did work. I don't want to be so hubristic as to assume that everyone who reads this solution will not be doing anything else wrong.